# Android JUnit4 runner does not run tests not starting with 'test'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

There is an ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 which has AndrodJUnit4 runner. there are test methods annotated with @Test. however it seems methods which do not starting with 'test' prefix are not executed at all through gradle command (Android Studio does not have this problem).

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MyActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyActivity> {


  public MyActivityTest() {
    super(MyActivity.class);
  }

  @Before
  public void setup() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());

    getActivity();
  }

  @Test
  public void testOne() {
    // this runs from gradle
  }

  @Test
  public void two() {
    // this does not run from gradle. However runds from Android Studio
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
  }
}
```

### Snippet from build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        ....
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'
    ...

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2')

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.3')
}
```

Comment: @RunWith(AndroidJunit4.class) is important to use in every instrumentation test case because it provides a runner for running our test in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me you are using JUnit 3 not JUnit 4, you do not extend from the `InstrumentTestCase2` instead you use the `@Rule` annotation.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class ApplicationTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MyActivity> mActivityRule = 
        new ActivityTestRule<>(MyActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void listGoesOverTheFold() {
        onView(withText("Hello world!")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }

    @Test
    public void assertFail(){
        assertFalse(false);

    }

}
```